# My function is triggering twice after the DOM changes react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm practicing my skills in react, and I want to do this app: https://pokemon-game-xyz-vue.netlify.app/, my app is working fine, but there is something rare that is happening. I create a js file helper where in that function return the URL for the picture of the pokemon and also randomPokemon.

so... in the beginning works well, but after I click with the correct name, the color of my img change which is fine, but "gettingPokemon" trigger again and the image changes. so that means my function is  triggering twice when the DOM changes.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { GetImage } from "./components/GetImage";
import { useFetch } from "./hooks/usefetch";
import { gettingPokemon} from "./helpers/gettingRandomPokemon"


export const App = () => {
  
  const {pokemon1,pokemon2,pokemon3,pokemon4,isLoading} = useFetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon`)

  const [comparacion, setComparacion] = useState(false)
   
  const {randomPokemon,urlRandomPokemn} = gettingPokemon(pokemon1,pokemon2,pokemon3,pokemon4)
  
  const  getName = (e) => {
    let pickPokemonName = e.target.id
    if(pickPokemonName === randomPokemon?.name) {
      setComparacion(true)
      
    } else {
      setComparacion(false)
    }
  }
 


  
  return (
    <>
    <h1>quien es ese pokemon?</h1>
    <hr />

   {
     (!isLoading) && <GetImage urlRandomPokemon={urlRandomPokemn} comparacion={comparacion}></GetImage>
   }
    

    {
      (isLoading) && <div className="alert alert-info text-center">
        Loading...
      </div>
    }

    {
      (!isLoading) &&
        <>
          <ul>
            <li><button onClick={getName} id={pokemon1.name} >{pokemon1.name}</button></li>
            <li><button onClick={getName} id={pokemon2.name} >{pokemon2.name}</button></li>
            <li><button onClick={getName} id={pokemon3.name} >{pokemon3.name}</button></li>
            <li><button onClick={getName} id={pokemon4.name} >{pokemon4.name}</button></li>
          </ul>
          
          
          
        </>
    }

   
    </>
  )
}
```

```
export const gettingPokemon = (pokemon1,pokemon2,pokemon3,pokemon4) => {
  

    let pokemones = [pokemon1,pokemon2,pokemon3,pokemon4]
    let randomPokemon = pokemones[Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemones.length)]
    let urlRandomPokemn = randomPokemon?.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default 
    console.log('me dispare otra vez');

    return {
        randomPokemon,
        urlRandomPokemn,
    
    }
}
```

```
export const GetImage = ({urlRandomPokemon,comparacion}) => {

  return (
    
           <img src={urlRandomPokemon} alt='' className={(comparacion) ? 'claro' : 'oscuro'}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please remember to format and indent your code properly so folks can read it.

Comment: sorry, my bad, i just edited.

Comment: Why are there still loads of empty lines and weird indents? Tell your code editor to automatically format your code (e.g. using `prettier` or the like) so that it's easier to read for both "readers on Stackoverflow" _and_ yourself =)

Comment: also suffering inconsistencies like `useFecth` vs `usefetch` and misspellings like `urlRandomPokemn`, mixture of English and Spanish names like `comparacion`. some lines have semicolons, others don't.

Comment: useFecth vs usefetch tahts a little bit rare, i use the autocomplete import, but i already changed in my code and is working. I just notice urlRandomPokemn. i missed the "o".

Comment: @FreddyAlexSaavedra have you resolved the issue... was if simply code typos.  If so, post that as an answer and close the question.

Comment: @FreddyAlexSaavedra just checked out your game pretty cool... I have some questions about how you made it... can we get in touch?

Comment: @FlakDiNenno yes for sure, you can check the game here with all the code, take a look on my github https://github.com/fass28/react-pokemon-game,  go at README, you will be find the link netlify how is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Functional React components are, as the name suggests, just functions. Each time you change any state in your component that React is aware of (such as from props, or via the `setComparacion` setter in your onClick handlers), the function will re-run again, and any code in it will be re-run as well.

If you want to preserve data across renders, you want to use `useState` to create and keep state variables, or (more likely in this case) `useMemo` to prevent code from re-running unless dependent variables change.

In this case, you probably want something like:

```js
const { randomPokemon, urlRandomPokemn } = useMemo(
  () => gettingPokemon(pokemon1, pokemon2, pokemon3, pokemon4),
  [pokemon1, pokemon2, pokemon3, pokemon4]
);
```

What this does is say "run this function if hasn't been run at all, or when any of the values in the variables `[pokemon1, pokemon2, pokemon3, pokemon4]` change, otherwise give me the value of the last time it ran". The component may re-render as many times as necessary, but unless one of the four dependent values changes, `gettingPokemon` will not get re-run, which will preserve your randomly-selected value.

Comment: thanks so much for the reply my friend, it worked, i as struggling with this, im new in react and useMemo, useEffect, useCallback is a little bit hard to understand.  again, thanks so much

Comment: React has to know *when* to re-render a component. It does this by recognizing when the props passed to a component have changed, or when the state (set by a useState setter or an ancestor Context) that a component depends on has changed. Then, when a component is running, useEffect lets you run code conditionally in response to changes in arbitrary values in the component (without a return value), useMemo is like useEffect, except it returns a value, and useCallback is like a specialized useMemo for returning functions.